# How do I make a try, except: block for this error?

Tags: python

Whenever Photoshop does not have a document open, I get this error:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Adobe Photoshop', 'No such element', None, 0, -2147352565), None)
```

which is PERFECTLY FINE: all I need to do is make a

```
try:

except:
```

block. However, I cannot except the error. I tried writing

```
except pywintypes.com_error:
```

however that did not work. So, how do I import the error into my py file?

EDIT::

I fixed it by typing

```
from pywintypes import com_error
```

Comment: Actually, I literally just found the answer.

I needed to do this:

from pywintypes import com_error.

I would have done this myself, but instead I had been writing COMError, and that didn't work.

Comment: Also, it's probably better if you'd make a check (are there any documents?) instead of raising an exception

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy

I'm not sure how to do this in the Photoshop documentation. I'm not that great at coding.

Is there any reason NOT to have an error, as long as it doesn't cause any issues when you run it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by typing this:

```
from pywintypes import com_error
```